# Using Scrapy to use a website's search function

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am kind of a rookie using Scrapy, just starting to use it.

I've just found myself stuck on a part because I can't seem to find anything online on it nor anything similar asked on stackoverflow!

I am basically reading a few lines from a .csv file and I wanna use the search function on this website 'http://collectorsfrenzy.com/'

How should I go around this?

Comment: That website seems to use following search pattern [ http://collectorsfrenzy.com/search?q={query} ], so append your search term to that, and scrape the resulted webpage.

Comment: @Grainier - Please add your comment on this question as an answer so that it can be accepted - comments may be lost over time but accepted answers will not be _plus it will up your rep of course_ - it would also be nice to generalise to "Try the search and look at the pattern of the URL in the search results, e.g. on the site you refer to this is..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to identify the search endpoint used within the website (i.e. `collectorsfrenzy.com/search?q={query}` in this scenario). Once you figured that out, append your search term to that and use it as starting point for crawling and scrape the resulting content.